# Is there a better way to execute this SQL statement in Spring using JdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, oracle

I have an SQL statement to select a `BRAND_NAME` based on an input parameter. The code goes something like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, Object>>> getBrand(String brandName){
    sql = "SELECT BRAND_NAME AS \"brandName\" FROM BRAND_E WHERE LOWER(BRAND_NAME) LIKE '%" + brandName + "%'";
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Map<String, Object>>>(jdbc.queryForList(sql), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I've found out that this can probably cause SQL injection attacks, so I was wondering how to code this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.If you directly use the request param on your sql it can lead to SQL injection attacks. We can always go with the prepared statement by adding a placeholder to where the values must be added.

Use `queryForList(String sql, Object... args)` or `queryForList(String sql, Object[] args, Class<T> elementType)`

Eg:-

```
String employeeId= "1";
String sql = "select id,name,address from employee where id = ?"; 
getJdbcTemplate(). queryForList(sql, new Object[]{employeeId}, Employee.class);
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't let me use `%?%` because I would be searching through brands that contain letters like that.

Comment: Can you try this - where LOWER(BRAND_NAME) like CONCAT( '%',?,'%')";

Comment: Can you paste the new query here ?